# Why do all of my circles connect in WebGL

Tags: javascript, graphics, webgl

I am working on a script that is supposed to generate 10 circles using triangle fans and they have randomly generated positions and colors. From what I can tell, it works mostly as intended other than the fact that all of my circles are connected to each other. It looks like there is always one point that connects from the previous circle to the next.

Here is my javascript code:

```js
var gl;
var points;
var pi = 3.1415;
var rad = 2 * pi / 360;
var colors = [];
var vertices = [];

window.onload = function init() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");
    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL(canvas);
    if (!gl) { alert("WebGL isn't available"); }
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var red = Math.random();
        var green = Math.random();
        var blue = Math.random();
        var r = Math.random() / 5 + .1;
        var xOff = Math.random() - .5;
        var yOff = Math.random() - .5;
        vertices.push(xOff);
        vertices.push(yOff);
        colors.push(red);
        colors.push(blue);
        colors.push(green);
        colors.push(1.0);
        for (var theta = 0; theta <= 360; theta += 1) {
            vertices.push(r*Math.cos(rad*theta) + xOff);
            vertices.push(r*Math.sin(rad*theta) + yOff);
            colors.push(red);
            colors.push(blue);
            colors.push(green);
            colors.push(1.0);
        }
    }

    //  Configure WebGL

    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    gl.clearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    
    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers
    
    var program = initShaders(gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader");
    gl.useProgram(program);
    
    // Load the data into the GPU
    
    var bufferId = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferId);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);  

    // Associate out shader variables with our data buffer
    
    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);
    
    var colorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    
    var aColor = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "aColor");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(aColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(aColor);
    
    render();
};

function render() {
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 362);
    for (i = 362; i < 3620; i += 362) {
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, i + 1, i + 362);
    }
}
```

I have tried changing the starting vertices and setting them manually because I thought maybe the circles had shared points, but that did not seem to be the case. I have also tried just making 2 circles by manually picking vertices, but for some reason it makes a 3rd and they are still connected. I am relatively new to WebGL and there is a good chance I misunderstand how the rendering and drawing arrays works but any tips or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[`drawArrays`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/drawArrays) last argument is the *count* of indices rather than the end of the range, you did "from index X to index Y" when you actually needed to render "Y indices starting at index X".

Also you should use `let` and `const` rather than `var` to avoid using undefined variables (like you did with your loop counters) and polluting your (and the global) scope. To avoid those mistakes in the future you can use `"use strict";` at the top of your script, or run your code as a module using `<script type="module">`.

```js
let gl;
let points;
const pi = Math.PI;
const rad = 2 * pi / 360;
const colors = [];
const vertices = [];

window.onload = function init() {
    const canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");
    // setupWebGL
    gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
    const br = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    gl.canvas.width = br.width;
    gl.canvas.height = br.height;
    
    if (!gl) { alert("WebGL isn't available"); }
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        const red = Math.random();
        const green = Math.random();
        const blue = Math.random();
        const r = Math.random() / 5 + .1;
        const xOff = Math.random() - .5;
        const yOff = Math.random() - .5;
        vertices.push(xOff);
        vertices.push(yOff);
        colors.push(red);
        colors.push(blue);
        colors.push(green);
        colors.push(1.0);
        for (let theta = 0; theta <= 360; theta += 1) {
            vertices.push(r*Math.cos(rad*theta) + xOff);
            vertices.push(r*Math.sin(rad*theta) + yOff);
            colors.push(red);
            colors.push(blue);
            colors.push(green);
            colors.push(1.0);
        }
    }

    //  Configure WebGL

    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    gl.clearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    
    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers
    
    const program = gl.createProgram();
    // initShaders
    const vs = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    const fs = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(vs, `
    attribute vec2 vPosition;
    attribute vec4 aColor;
    varying vec4 color;
    void main(){
        color=aColor;
        gl_Position=vec4(vPosition,0,1);
    }`);
    gl.shaderSource(fs, `
    precision mediump float;
    varying vec4 color;
    void main(){gl_FragColor=color;}
    `);
    gl.compileShader(vs);
    gl.compileShader(fs);
    gl.attachShader(program, vs);
    gl.attachShader(program, fs);
    gl.linkProgram(program);
    gl.useProgram(program);
    
    // Load the data into the GPU
    
    const bufferId = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferId);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);  

    // Associate out shader variables with our data buffer
    
    const vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);
    
    const colorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    
    const aColor = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "aColor");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(aColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(aColor);
    
    render();
};

function render() {
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    for (let i = 0; i < 3620; i+=362)
      gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN,i,362);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gl-canvas"></canvas>
```